# mysqldump exports only one table on other table

Tags: mysql, dump

I want to dump one table on other server. This is my command:

```
mysqldump -h xxxx -u xxxx -p xxxx shema_nme table_name >dump.sql
```

but I had every time the error: couldn't find table xxx

Can you please help me on the syntax?

Comment: did you check if you're using the correct schema/db name?

Comment: Yes the schema and the table name is correct.But does my command is correct?

Comment: if it wasn't correct, you'd get an error for unknown argument or whatever, not "can't find table". so you're specifying the wrong db/table. or connecting to the wrong server.

Comment: Thanks Marc for your clarify

Answer (score 0):

**Dump from remote server follow this**

```
mysqldump -u <db_username> -h <db_host> -p db_name table_name > table_name.sql
```

**Local database dump**

```
mysqldump db_name table_name > table_name.sql
```

and,Make sure your **db_username,db_password** and **db_host**